# Sub query on large table with join extremely slow

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-performance

I have the following query,

```
SELECT * FROM users, 
(SELECT * 
FROM mastery 
WHERE champion_rank = 1 
ORDER BY global_rank ASC 
LIMIT 3) as ranks
WHERE users.id = ranks.user_id
```

Mastery has 22M rows and users has 5M rows. The query above takes 1800ms to complete.

The problem is that the following sub query when run by itself takes 2.5ms to execute

```
SELECT * 
FROM mastery 
WHERE champion_rank = 1 
ORDER BY global_rank ASC 
LIMIT 3
```

And to retrieve a single user from users table takes 2.5ms

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = 4234523
```

So theoretically if i just modified my code to do the first subquery, and then for each row returned run an additional query the entire process would takes 2.5 + (3 * 2.5) = 10 ms to run.

Surely postgres is doing something weird?

Structure and indexes of databases can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/konk353535/eb585bf5877e860409b47e0bf78e9795)

Comment: why not use a join? Also, have you put indexes on the table?

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info and http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/SlowQueryQuestions then [edit] your question and add the missing information

Answer (score 0):

Your query runs slow because it has to run the sorted subquery for each on of the 5M rows in users.

You would be much better off doing a join single pass, and use rank() window function to filter the 3 top ones you want:

```
SELECT users.*, (ranks.mastery).*
FROM (
  SELECT mastery, rank() OVER (ORDER BY global_rank)
  FROM mastery
  WHERE champion_rank = 1
  ) as ranks
JOIN users ON (users.id = ranks.user_id)
WHERE ranks.rank <= 3;
```

Comment: Thanks this works awesome, i solved this by changing the data type of mastery.user_id and users.id to be the same but this is slightly more performant. Don't 100% understand it but will try when i get home from work

Answer (score 0):

Determined the issue, the data type for the two field i was joining were different. Mastery's user id was data type numeric and Users id was data type integer, it must of been casting each row to the new type.

Hence the long query time.

Comment: Which is something that could have been seen in the execution plan if you had added that to your question.

Comment: Im definetly not a postgres expert, i did take a look at the EXPLAIN ANALYZE of the query but from that was not intuitively able to figure out that this was the issue, but i think this is largely due to my inexperience with postgres

Comment: What I meant was: you should have added the execution plan to your initial question. Most probably somebody would have spotted that right away.